# Convert standard 24 hour format to a range of 99 python

Tags: python

The task is to convert an input in seconds to a time that is readable for humans in the format HH:MM:SS.

```
import time

def make_readable(seconds):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(seconds))
```

So far this is what I have, and it works.

The only problem is that the hours should be displayed in a range from 00 - 99, currently it is in 24 hours.

e.g. with an input of 359999 seconds, it should output 99:59:59. This is also the maximum time by the way.

Errors:

'00:00:00' should equal '24:00:00'

'03:59:59' should equal '99:59:59'

'20:36:54' should equal '44:36:54'

Question: How to put the hours in the 99 format?

Comment: what should happen for `1_000_000` seconds?

Comment: @corsiKa you will not get more than an input of 359999

Answer (score 0):

I think you can roll your own seconds parser. For example:

```
def make_readable(seconds):
    if seconds > 359999:
        raise ValueError('Invalid number of seconds: {}'.format(seconds))

    s = seconds % 60
    seconds //= 60

    m = seconds % 60
    seconds //= 60

    h = seconds

    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m, s)

print(make_readable(359999)) # Prints 99:59:59
print(make_readable(65)) # Prints 00:01:05
```

Comment: Thanks! could you please exaplain this part : ` return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m, s)` ? I do not fully understand what happens here. And also; how can h = seconds work? :o

Comment: Sure! The `h = seconds` part is just for readability (the remainder works out to be the number of hours). The `{:02d}` is a format string that indicates a 0-padded decimal of length 2. Here's a good place to learn about string formats: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Great, very useful website as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) instead of the `time` module.

```
def make_readable(seconds):
    hours, rem = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)

    # The following makes sure a one-digit time quantity is written as 0X
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Here are output examples.

```
make_readable(359999) # '99:59:59'
make_readable(3661)  # '01:01:01'

# This will continue working over 35,999 seconds
make_readable(360000) # '100:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what does the 'rem' stand for?

Comment: It's the remainder of divmod. divmode does an integer division and returns what could not be divided, which in that case are the seconds below 3600.

Comment: @Daphne here if you want to read more about it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod

Comment: ah I see, sort of like the modulo but then in a method, nice

Comment: Yes, but modulo only returns the remainder